# Alternative to AlwaysAppendSearchDomains on Yosemite?

Tags: macos, dns

Since Lion, I have used the AlwaysAppendSearchDomains trick on mDNSresponder to resolve names with dots in search domains.

In yosemite this doesn't work any more. In fact, mDNSresponder doesn't seem to be running:

```
$ ps ax | grep -i dns | grep -v grep
$
```

Answer (score 5):

I found the answer as I posted this:

To enable mDNSResponder, edit /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist and remove the lines

```
<key>Disabled</key>
<true/>
```

Then add -AlwaysAppendSearchDomains to the arguments list further down in the same file:

```
<string>_mdnsresponder</string>
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>/usr/sbin/mDNSResponder</string>
    <string>-AlwaysAppendSearchDomains</string>
</array>
```

Finally run

```
$ sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist
$ sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist
```

You can then verify mDNSResponder is running:

```
$ ps ax | grep -i dns | grep -v grep
10456   ??  Ss     0:00.44 /usr/sbin/mDNSResponder -AlwaysAppendSearchDomains
```

Subdomains of search domains can then be resolved.

Comment: It looks like `mDNSResponder` has been replaced by `discoveryd` in the latest Yosemite DP. Any idea how to achieve that with the new subsystem?

Comment: @cassianoleal, I, too, am curious about this. I [posted a follow-up question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151101/discoveryd-alternative-to-replace-mdnsresponder-argument) asking essentially the same thing. Here's hoping that the only option isn't to have to type FQDNs.

Comment: Also wanting to know how to achieve this with `discoveryd`