# Discoveryd Alternative to Replace mDNSResponder Argument?

Tags: network, dns, macos

This is a direct follow-on to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/140160/alternative-to-alwaysappendsearchdomains-on-yosemite). [Before Yosemite](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24018/dns-lookups-fail-with-e-g-ping-but-work-with-host/24551#24551), I'd add the "-AlwaysAppendSearchDomains" argument to the mDNSResponder plist file so that all local resolver lookups added the search domains, regardless of whether there was a period in the label to be looked up. For example, whether I try to ssh to hostname foo.bar or foo, the search domain of baz.com should be tried, not only for the latter case, as was (and is) the default behavior.

Now, it looks like the mDNSResponder is gone, replaced with discoveryd. I cannot find a similar option to get it to always appending the search domain. Suggestions? I'd rather not go the route of using a non-default local resolver, but I'd consider it as an option. For now, I'll just type in the long FQDNs, but I'd really rather not.

Thanks,
Pete

Comment: I previously had tried to enable the disabled mDNSResponder but since DP8, that seems absent altogether :( I've got a support ticket escalated to the Yosemite engineers now about the -AlwaysAppendSearchDomains option and how to handle this with discoveryd so I will post any further findings here when they contact me in a few days.

Comment: @djh, any luck with the Apple engineers?

Comment: This is fixed as part of the [10.10.1](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204017) update: `Allows you to append search domains for partially qualified domain names when performing DNS lookups (consult the discoveryd man page for more information)`. See @Teknisten's answer below.

Comment: This appears to be less relevant on newer versions of macOS since they have removed discoveryd in 10.10.4 https://www.macrumors.com/2015/06/30/apple-releases-os-x-10-10-4/

Answer (score 18):

Since 10.10.1, the simplest way to fix this is to add `--AlwaysAppendSearchDomains` to `ProgramArguments` in plist file `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.discoveryd.plist`

Then restart `com.apple.discoveryd.plist` with:

```
sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.discoveryd.plist
sudo launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.discoveryd.plist
```

All this according to the help printed by:

```
/usr/libexec/discoveryd --help
```

That will do the same as it did for mDNSResponder as far as I can tell.

Comment: Not working in El Capitan unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

Run **sudo discoveryutil mdnsactivedirectory yes** in Terminal. According to https://discussions.apple.com/message/26927843#26927843 it is the solution.

This can be made to run automatically whenever launching a terminal without a password:

- sudo visudo

  - add a line to the bottom `%admin ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/discoveryutil`
  - If admin group doesn't work, run `groups` at the terminal and use an appropriate group - perhaps 'staff' or 'everyone'. Or just use an individual username without the leading `%`
- To test visudo change

  - sudo -k
  - `sudo su` and verify that you **are** asked for password. Then control-c without entering your password
  - `sudo discoveryutil mdnsactivedirectory` and verify that you **aren't** asked for password
- Add a line to ~/.bash_profile `sudo discoveryutil mdnsactivedirectory yes`
- Add Terminal to your user's Login Items

  - on 10.10: System Preferences->Users & Groups, Select User
  - Goto "Login Items" tab, and add /Applications/Utilities/Terminal

Comment: How do you make this permanent? After a reboot you will need to execute this command again.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me, at least wrt non-.local hostnames. I still need to type "ssh foo.bar.baz.com" instead of "ssh foo.bar", even though ".baz.com" is in my search path.

Comment: You shouldn't add in a user `~/.bash_profile` a configuration modification which has to be made at the level of the system daemon, here `discoveryd`.

Answer (score 1):

No solution unfortunately, but I've found out you can at least check the resolver config using 'discoveryutil', like so:

```
mdbraber-mba:~ mdbraber$ sudo discoveryutil configresolver
Configuration Resolvers: Resolver domain [default], type Unicast, ifIndex 4, port 0, timeout 30, A yes, AAAA no, serviceID 0, scope None, order 0
    server 192.168.143.1
    search domain ourhouse
Configuration Resolvers: Resolver domain [default], type Unicast, ifIndex 4, port 0, timeout 30, A yes, AAAA no, serviceID 0, scope InterfaceID, order 0
    server 192.168.143.1
```

Apparently the first resolver lists a searchdomain, although it doesn't seem to work as under OS X < 10.10 versions. No idea why there is a second resolver without a search domain listed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hacked up solution using a local nameserver - works for me:

https://github.com/joedj/yosemite_dnsfix

Comment: It would be better to add the solution as part of the answer, otherwise if the link ever disappears, the answer becomes useless. You can edit your own post to add it.