# How do I configure Yosemite to be able to resolve DNS ending in ".local"?

Tags: macos

Yosemite doesn't seem to understand any domain that ends in .local

My DNS server is pointed at the ip of the debian box, which runs dnsmasq.

It has a ton of apache sites configured that all have names like clientname.debserver.local - all which resolve fine from the other machines around the lan (not Yosemite).

(tried flushing cache, resetting network, rebooting, all the usual suspects)

Answer (score 11):

[Apple has provided some related documentation here](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT6569).  In which they recommend avoiding `.local` if you can and instead using a suffix such as `.private`, `.intranet`, `.internal`, or `.lan`.

The reason `.local` should be avoided is because it's used by the Bonjour service.

---

### Short Answer

Add the following Search Domain as in the screenshot (you can disregard my DNS Server settings):

[image]

---

### Long Answer

Another possibility is documented here in an article about [using Dnsmasq for local development on OS X](http://passingcuriosity.com/2013/dnsmasq-dev-osx/) and a [related StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26840768/yosemite-localhost-resolver-and-dnsmasq-fails-offline) in which someone seems to have found it successful except when their offline (which doesn't make a lot of since.. but the key point here is, it seems to work for them at least part of the time)

The linked article directs that you should create a directory at `/etc/resolver` if it doesn't already exist by using the command

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/resolver
```

> Now you should create a new file in this directory for each resolver you want to configure.  Configure with at least these two options (there are more options available):
>
> - the name of the resolver (corresponding to the domain name)
> - the DNS server to be used.
>
> For more information about these files, see the `resolver(5)` manual page:
>
> `man 5 resolver`
>
> Create a new file with the same name as your new top-level domain in the `/etc/resolver/` directory and add a nameserver to it by running the following commands:
>
> `sudo tee /etc/resolver/local >/dev/null <<EOF`
> `nameserver 127.0.0.1`
> `EOF`
>
> Here `local` is the top-level domain name configured to respond to and `127.0.0.1` is the IP address of the server to use.

I looked to see if I had that directory by default and I did not, but I did notice I had a file `/etc/resolv.conf` which existed by default.  I have not attempted, but if the solution in the article is unsuccessful I would try using this pre-existing `resolv.conf` file.. under the assumption.. *it must be there for a reason*.

Answer (score 1):

Apple does not resolve `.local` using a DNS server, but Apple Bonjour its `zeroconf` impementation. You could install `Avahi` the Linux and BSD implementation.

I use `netatalk` on my Linux boxes to communicate with OS X

Answer (score 1):

See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/152892/65787 for a way to automate `sudo discoveryutil mdnsactivedirectory yes` which forces DNS resolution of .local domains on Yosemite.

Answer (score 0):

If you have just the one Mac and the ip addresses don't change, you can bypass the whole problem and put the name/address in /etc/hosts. People forget, there was a time before DNS where we kept the hosts files synched by uucp'ing them around.