# Cannot reach a .local domain without setting an option with discoveryutil

Tags: macos, dns

I have a .local website at: mysite.myname.local

If I try to http mysite.myname.local in a browser, nothing happens.

If I 'ping mysite.myname.local', it reports 'ping: cannot resolve mysite.myname.local: Unknown host'.

If I 'nslookup mysite.myname.local', it will report the correct IP Address.

If I 'host mysite.myname.local', it will also report the correct IP Address.

However, if I leave off myname.local from the ping and http:// address, 'ping mysite' and http mysite will both work as expected.

I used tcpdump to see if it would tell me anything and the only clue I spotted in there was:

> 0:36:07.466728 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 52932, offset 0, flags [none],
>   proto UDP (17), length 67, bad cksum 0 (->221a)!)
>       192.168.4.122.59479 > 192.168.4.1.domain: [bad udp cksum 0x8a0c -> 0x7ba3!] 27737+ A? mysite.myname.local. (39) 10:36:07.467151 IP (tos
>   0x0, ttl 64, id 6826, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length
>   97)
>       192.168.4.1.domain > 192.168.4.122.59479: [udp sum ok] 27737* q: A? mysite.myname.local. 1/1/0 mysite.myname.local. [1m] A
>   192.168.4.235 ns: mysite.myname.local. [1m] NS mysite.myname.local. (69)

so, it looks like there is a bad cksum somewhere.

In order to be able to specify the complete address, I found the discussion [Trouble to access ".local" domain](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6611817) in which someone suggested the following command 'sudo discoveryutil mdnsactivedirectory yes'

Once I execute this command, 'ping mysite.myname.local' and http'ing to mysite.myname.local both work.

I have couple of questions:

1. Is there a way to modify /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.discoveryd.plist to turn on mdnsactivedirectory after a reboot? If so, what do I need to add to the plist?
2. Can anyone explain what is going on? I am not sure I understand what the problem really is or why that discoveryutil command fixes it.

Comment: See http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/152892/65787 for a way to automate using ~/.bash_profile, visudo NOPASSWD, and putting Terminal in Login Items.  I'm sure there's a way using LaunchDaemons, but this works, so I'm not messing with it further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an answer posted to this [discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/message/27173761?ac_cid=op123456#27173761).

> Linc Davis
>
> The "local" TLD is reserved for Bonjour. The restriction was not
>   enforced in older versions of OS X, but it is in Yosemite. Unicast
>   domain names with that TLD will not resolve by default. To make your
>   configuration change permanent (not recommended), create your own
>   launch daemon. Don't modify an existing one. See the launchd.plist(5)
>   man page for details. A much better solution would be to change the
>   domain name.

There is a wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.local) on the .local domain which does state:

> Internet Engineering Task Force (IETF) standards-track RFC 6762, which
>   has been approved and was officially published on February 20, 2013,
>   essentially reserves the use of .local as a pseudo-TLD for link-local
>   hostnames that can be resolved via the Multicast DNS name resolution
>   protocol.

So, the answer is that I should not be using .local in the way I am currently using it in order to comply with current standards.