# Catalina cannot resolve servers in the .local domain without the domain being specified

Tags: network, dns, bonjour, domain

---

---

**tl;dr** In the Catalina terminal *ping lan-services.local* works but *ping lan-services* does not

---

---

I have a 2012 Mac mini that I just installed Catalina on from scratch (i.e. blank SSD and USB install) connected to a home network via Ethernet that cannot find servers / devices on the LAN without appending '.local' to the name.  This was not needed before Catalina on the same LAN set-up (i.e. the only thing I can think of that's changed is the OS on the Mac).

e.g.

```
~% ping lan-services
ping: cannot resolve lan-services: Unknown host
~ % ping lan-services.local
PING lan-services.local (192.168.1.10): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.1.10: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=5.480 ms
...
^C
```

#### Network Config for Ethernet

- IPv4 configured *Using DHCP*
- IPv6 configured *Link-local only*
- DNS set to *1.1.1.1* and *208.67.220.220* (set by router)
- Advanced / DNS / Search Domains is *local* (no dot as per help examples)
- Mac Firewall is *OFF*
- Everything else has not been changed (i.e. default to Catalina)

#### /etc/hosts file

No entries have been added (where not needed on Mojave)

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

#### VPN and Anti-Virus

- VPN software installed BUT **NOT** active - this is the same as the previous Mojave install
- Two VPNs Windscribe and Bitdefender (I could not load Bitdefender without its VPN software)
- Disabling Bitdefender 'Shield' does not help

#### Target servers / devices

- Internet router is DNS server with a default domain as *local*
- Some set up as static IPv4 in their config files - some dynamic
- Internet router has static IPv4 assignments for the servers / devices
- ISP does not support IPv6 so the router is set to RADVD (link-local) but NOT bound to an external interface
- Finder correctly shows the server I am trying to PING
- Finder opens the server shares fine (it is a Pi using Netatalk / AFP for file sharing **NOT** SMB)
- Some devices have IPv4 only, some have IPv4 and IPv6 stacks loaded
- No devices has any firewall settings that would stop PING or SSH

#### scutil --dns output

```
DNS configuration

resolver #1
  search domain[0] : local
  nameserver[0] : 1.1.1.1
  nameserver[1] : 208.67.220.220
  if_index : 5 (en1)
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000002 (Reachable)

resolver #2
  domain   : local
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 300000

resolver #3
  domain   : 254.169.in-addr.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 300200

resolver #4
  domain   : 8.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 300400

resolver #5
  domain   : 9.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 300600

resolver #6
  domain   : a.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 300800

resolver #7
  domain   : b.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 301000

DNS configuration (for scoped queries)

resolver #1
  search domain[0] : local
  nameserver[0] : 1.1.1.1
  nameserver[1] : 208.67.220.220
  if_index : 5 (en1)
  flags    : Scoped, Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000002 (Reachable)
```

#### Things checked

- A search turned up [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/158088/cannot-reach-a-local-domain-without-setting-an-option-with-discoveryutil) (though it seems to be a
  reverse issue) and the solution of adding *mdnsactivedirectory* via
  *discoveryutil* but that program seems to have been deprecated in Catalina - this was not required in Mojave.
- I may not be the only one having this issue (going by this Apple Forum [question](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250874035)) but no domain is shown and the 'hint' is either
  talk to Apple or look at Active Directory (not installed here).
- Turning on [file sharing](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7707202) does not help.
- Checked sons Windows 10 PC - he can reach devices without the .local as well as devices with the .local (pin lan-services checked
  **before** pin lan-services.local) and is running iTunes for his music.
- A note from above test today I'm not running iTunes as Apple changed to iTune to the Music App
- Just installed [Discovery - DNS-SD Browser](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/discovery-dns-sd-browser/id1381004916?mt=12) from eh App Store (thanks to Lily Ballard for this FOC package). This shows its picking up services from AFP over TCP and picking up all the devices on my home LAN (easier to play with):
  [image]

#### Workarounds I'm trying to avoid

1. Adding entries into /etc/hosts
2. Adding .local to the end of each server name by hand - me being lazy (though this is what I am currently doing)
3. Installing ANOTHER DHCP / DNS server (e.g. pi-hole / pfSense etc)
4. Downgrading to Mojave
5. Moving to SMB shares - one server does not seem to support SMB without a whole series of faff for security and performance is pathetic. TBH also I do not have a great deal of practice with SAMBA security (basic shares fine) and no spare cash in project to upgrade old servers if Samba does not run on them.

Comment: Can you include the output of the Terminal command "scutil --dns" ?

Comment: Edited main question to show scutil --dns (not a command I know so Google here I come).

Comment: Very Quick Google infers this is to set local DNS server for mdns / bonjour I take it record two shows no server from reach but do not know how to correct.  Please see notes on iTune / Bonjour in question. Appologies for delay - think I am suffering from Viral Labyrinthitis and may not be able to get back for a day or so - Screen making it worse despite anti-nausea drugs / trying to sleep it off.  Going to ring NHS help line.

Comment: As you seem to have discovered, *local* is a special TLD route on Apple machines. This may not be the solution you are looking for, but I had similar problem earlier this year and ended up sidestepping it entirely by using the *internal* TLD instead of *local* with my DNS. If you have any control whatsoever over your internal router’s default DNS, changing that is what is recommended. If you search online, there is a list of TLDs recommended for intranet use (though internal TLD is overall discouraged). You will note that *local* is not in this list for this very reason

Comment: Note that another workaround is for you to set a static IP for your intranet services and use the IPV4 to resolve (eg set 192.168.1.10 as static on the router for the service machine and then on the client resolve using that instead of lan-services.local). I am not sure what the ramifications are of trying to get around the built in .local DNS behavior on the Apple machine which seems to be what you are asking how to do but doing so could risk breaking some ITunes/Bonjour functionality on the machine if you do so.

Comment: I'm back with a pile of tablets, blurry eyes and a splitting headache! Not sure I'm breaking mDNS as I'm telling the Mac to search local by default in search domains in Sys Pref / Network / Advanced / DNS... One target is static in router and device but ssh -4 still fails to resolve with config above - time to play with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38867905/how-to-view-dns-cache-in-osx I think

Comment: Think I'm going to have to merge my DNS and DHCP to one box to give me more control over the local / internal.  I know .local is a **total** mess (See Microsoft build notes et. al) but I have no AD to worry about only history :-). I wish ICANN would get of the fence over this (mega-money been offered for .local **I assume**) gggrrrr...  For any folk baffled what @Conor and I are talking about see https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6762#appendix-G and https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/name-collision-it-pros-faqs-2014-08-01-en

Comment: In fact ICAAN get worse. Their IT Guide states 'ICANN has stated that it will indefinitely defer delegating three TLDs: .corp, .home, and .mail. These gTLDs are still in common use in private namespaces' but qualifies it with 'The deferral is not guaranteed to be forever'...  They even published a note in 2013 stating they have an option to BLOCK a gTLD but IANA have had to put local in their special use list due to rfc6762 as ICANN(ot) does not seem to want to do this (rant over)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

I tried to SSH to my RaspberryPi from `raspberrypi.local`, but it wouldn't connect.
ping command did not connect too.

I was able to SSH connect and ping using the terminal app on my iPad.

In my case, the cause was the DNS settings.

On my Mac, DNS was set to 8.8.8.8.
So I removed the DNS record from Network System Preferences.
Then I was able to connect to SSH.

I still can't reach the ping, but it's good that I can connect to SSH.

Comment: That is a different problem the questions says ping lan-services.local works but ping lan-services doesn't So for the OP raspberrypi.local would work

Comment: Well it might work - the issue for you is if the raspberry is configure to use mDNS and that is a subject for another forum, - I think there is a Raspberry on if not then SuperUser

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behaviour

.local is a special extension It is documented in [rfc6762](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6762)

As the abstract says

> In particular, the ability
> to look up DNS resource record data types (including, but not limited
> to, host names) in the absence of a conventional managed DNS server
> is useful.

So looking for x.local does not use any DNS server and x will not appear in any DNS so there is no network it can be addresses simply as x on.

Apple's implementation of this protocol is called Bonjour and is on Apple devices.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.local)
It might be implemented in Windows 10

> Although Windows operating systems often do not have built-in mDNS function, it can be added by installing zeroconf software available from Apple and other third parties, and it is beginning to be added in Windows 10.

For Linux it says

> Most Linux distributions also incorporate and are configured to use zero configuration networking. By default, each computer’s Avahi daemon will respond to mDNS hostname.local queries, and most shell commands and application program calls that attempt to resolve such names are routed to that daemon by the default hosts: line in the Name Service Switch configuration file. It is also possible to configure the nss-mdns modules and Avahi to resolve hostnames with other pseudo-TLDs.

So you might have to do extra work on non Apple machines

Answer (score -1):

Not a great solution but it seems that you need to have a DNS server that lives on the .local domain for Macs to be able to search correctly now.

The standard UK ee Router / Modem box does not have any options for adding a domain into its config but as soon as the router was swapped for a 2nd hand TP-Link one everything was OK.

Going back to the ee Router caused the same issues till a pi-hole system was built and put on the LAN as the first DNS server then everything was OK.

- Pi-Hole did not need configuring as DHCP
- Pi-Hole did not need to act as an ad-block

I've since moved over to using pi-hole v5 as the DNS/DHCP server and its now handling devices across a WiFi bridge (yet another Pi) and Airport Extreme fine.

***Thanks to Conor for the initial thought of setting the router up*** - lead me to check the router domain options.

Note: I **think** the ee router defaults to a domain of .home going from the odd entry or two in its log but as that's now in storage I'm not fussed and the Tp-Link box gives a more stable connection as well.